# Passing a value from input text field to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I am creating a skid, I am trying to get a value that user has entered so that I can create that record that many times.

in _form.html.erb is where all my code sits.  and in the new.html.erb is where I call the form with:

`<%= render 'form' %>`

Here is the piece of code from form that I am trying to access:

```
  <%= f.label :skid_count %>
  <%= f.number_field :skid_count, :value => '1', :required => 'required', :pattern => ValidationValues.c_integer, :placeholder => ValidationValues.p_integer %>
```

In the controller I am trying to do this:

```
    def create
    @skid = Skid.new(params[:skid])

    count = params[:skid_count].to_i

    # Create record in the database, and return an appropriate message
    respond_to do |format|
      if @skid.save
        for i in 1..count
          Skid.new(params[:skid]).save
        end

        format.html { redirect_to @skid, notice: 'Skid was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @skid, status: :created, location: @skid }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @skid.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

for some reason the count variable is not picking up the number, if I hard code it and put 3 in there, it would create the record 4 times just as intended, however if I try to get the numeric value based on what user entered, as shown above, it doesn't works.  It creates just 1 record every time.

Is there a reason why I cannot access that param?

Comment: Check the log and please post the parameters that are coming in with the request

Comment: @nachbar I don't know how to do that... could you please explain?  I'm very new to ruby and rails...

Comment: If you are running your test server in development mode, the log will be in the logs subdirectory of your Rails app, and be development.log  That file will list, for every request, all of the parameters being passed to Rails with the request, with a timestamp.  Also, if you are running the server in a terminal window, the parameters will show up there too, but might go by too fast to see them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this question by getting the value from the attribute in this manner:

```
count = params[:skid]["skid_count"]
```

I hope this helps somebody else stumbled with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's look like you are setting the variable before the record saves, so there is no record to set the variable with at that point. If you move the line down a few spaces, it should work.

```
def create
  @skid = Skid.new(params[:skid])

  # Create record in the database, and return an appropriate message
  respond_to do |format|
  if @skid.save
    count = params[:skid_count].to_i    # if the record saves, create variable with the new params
    for i in 1..count                   # do your magic
      Skid.new(params[:skid]).save
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

I will expand on your answer to explain why.

As you are building the field via the form_for helper, it automatically scopes it under the model attributes in the param hash.

`params[:skid][:skid_count]` would work as well

if you want `:skid_count` to be outside of the params hash (as to not to trigger forbidden attributes in newer versions of rails, you can build it by just using `number_field_tag(:skid_count)`  which would them be available to your controller as `params[:skid_count]`